# Javascript - Loading filtering external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I'm needing some advice on how to filter an external html file.

I can load the file just fine with the following code.

```
$('body').load('files/my-links.html', function(data) {
document.write(data) ;
}) ;
```

Since the file contains several classes in the links, I want to filter the links shown by class. Allowing me to put all the external links in one file, then show only the ones I want at any given time. I also want to limit the number of links that I display at any time. So if there's 25 links to the lunchbox class, I can show only 10 at one time.

I've tried putting the whole thing in an array, but that hasn't helped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply a selector to .load, for example:

```
$('body').load('files/my-links.html a:lt(10)');
```

It would do the same thing as using:

```
$.get('files/my-link.html',function(html){
    $('body').html($(html).find('a:lt(10)'));
});
```

`a:lt(10)` means select the first 10 anchor tags.

You can of course filter by your class too while your at it: `a.myclass` or `a.myclass:lt(10)`

Comment: I was unaware of the lt(#) deal, that's cool. Only problem is that the following load code doesn't filter on class or limit the number of links.  `$('body').load('files/mylinks.html a.baseball:lt(5)', function(data) {document.write(data) ;
});`

Comment: See edit, the load didn't need a callback, using `document.write()` overwrites what `$.fn.load` actually does.

Comment: That just about got it on the load(), of course now, the links all run together...the <br> tag at the end of the line goes missing. I'm thinking the $.get might be the way to go, except that it doesn't filter or limit in it's original state. Thanks.